# Character code from individual digits of octal representation

Tags: c

I have three individual characters, `int x,y,z`, and want to construct the character which has the octal representation `\xyz` from them. How can I achieve this?

I assume I need to use one of the many `*printf` variants, but unfortunately my own attempts didn't work and I couldn't find any other question on SO answering this.

Comment: Show your attempts and we will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: What if `x = 20`, `y = 30` and `z = 1234` ? BTW just wondering why someone with almost 4000 rep asks such a question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Top tag: Javascript.

Comment: @EOF I've seen that too, but still...

Comment: @MichaelWalz There's already validation that all three numbers are in the 0–7 range. Also, I didn't show my attempts because I knew they were too far off. It's a quite simple problem, so I think it justifies asking for the oneliner that does the job.

Comment: @IngoBürk see answer below which looks good to me.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, already tested it out and works. And I'm sorry a 4k rep person has to ask such a question, but sometimes… :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// 145 octal
int x = '1';
int y = '4';
int z = '5';

int octal = (x - '0') * 64 + (y - '0') * 8 + (z - '0');
```

If you have the value of the digits, do not subtract `'0'`

```
// 145 octal
int x = 1;
int y = 4;
int z = 5;

int octal = x * 64 + y * 8 + z;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! I'll accept it as soon as SO lets me.